# Pyspark - How to iterate thorough Dataframe applying calculations based on previous calculated field

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I'm using Pyspark to perform calculation in loop/recursively based on the previous value/result

I have a data like below in my dataframe.

| id | status | type | date | Expected | Expected Status Duration in Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | A | 1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 0 |
| ID1 | A | 2 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 1440 |
| ID1 | B | 1 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | 0 |
| ID1 | B | 2 | 2020-01-04 00:00:00 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | 1440 |
| ID1 | B | 3 | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | 2880 |
| ID1 | B | 2 | 2020-01-06 00:00:00 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | 4320 |
| ID1 | A | 1 | 2020-01-07 00:00:00 | 2020-01-07 00:00:00 | 2880 (as its assigned back to A) |
| ID1 | A | 1 | 2020-01-08 00:00:00 | 2020-01-07 00:00:00 | 4320 |
| ID1 | B | 1 | 2020-01-09 00:00:00 | 2020-01-09 00:00:00 | 5760 |
| ID1 | B | 1 | 2020-01-10 00:00:00 | 2020-01-09 00:00:00 | 7200 |
| ID1 | B | 1 | 2020-01-11 00:00:00 | 2020-01-09 00:00:00 | 8640 |
| ID1 | B | 1 | 2020-01-12 00:00:00 | 2020-01-09 00:00:00 | 10080 |

I'm trying to recursively calculate the date on when the Status for an ID had changed. And calculate the difference of the time (in Min) between the status changes.

If the previous status is same as current - the previous value of date should maintained but when the status changes the date should be updated.

I'm trying window function with Lag operation but that would not help this case, as the lag would take the existing value instead of computed value.

```
partition = Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy(F.col('DATE'))

df = (df
.withColumn("lag_sts",lag("STATUS",1).over(partition))
.withColumn("lag_date",lag("DATE",1).over(partition))
.withColumn("Expected", F.when(F.col("Status")==F.col("lag_sts"),F.col("lag_date"))
.otherwise(F.col("DATE"))
)
```

This is how the data looks now.

| id | status | type | date | lag_grp | lag_date | Expected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | A | 1 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | null | null | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| ID1 | A | 2 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 | A | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 | 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| ID1 | B | 1 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | A | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 |
| ID1 | B | 2 | 2020-01-04 00:00:00 | B | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 |
| ID1 | B | 3 | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | B | 2020-01-04 00:00:00 | 2020-01-04 00:00:00 |
| ID1 | B | 2 | 2020-01-06 00:00:00 | B | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 | 2020-01-05 00:00:00 |
| ID1 | A | 1 | 2020-01-07 00:00:00 | B | 2020-01-06 00:00:00 | 2020-01-07 00:00:00 |
| ID1 | A | 1 | 2020-01-08 00:00:00 | A | 2020-01-07 00:00:00 | 2020-01-07 00:00:00 |
| ID1 | B | 1 | 2020-01-09 00:00:00 | A | 2020-01-08 00:00:00 | 2020-01-09 00:00:00 |
| ID1 | B | 1 | 2020-01-10 00:00:00 | B | 2020-01-09 00:00:00 | 2020-01-09 00:00:00 |
| ID1 | B | 1 | 2020-01-11 00:00:00 | B | 2020-01-10 00:00:00 | 2020-01-10 00:00:00 |
| ID1 | B | 1 | 2020-01-12 00:00:00 | B | 2020-01-11 00:00:00 | 2020-01-11 00:00:00 |

I'm new to pyspark and in learning phase so looking for suggestions and sample code.

Comment: it doesn't look like you are getting value based on the previous value. Instead looks like you are getting the first/min `Date` per `ID`&`Status`.  Is that what you are expecting to have?

Comment: No, but looks like that is one way to approach the solution. But what if I have some calculation that I need to cascade to Expected result.

Comment: Right, so I wanted to differentiate first of all does your data ever `ID1 | B | 3-JAN-2020` appears before `ID1 | B | 2-JAN-2020`?  and in this case, do you need to carry `3-JAN-2020` for other `ID1 | B` rows?  If this is not the case, I think the logic I describe is easier to implement.

Comment: Yes this is very much possible. It will not always be first/min based on ID/Status. There are few calculation that are required like how long it was in a particular status etc.

Comment: Hmm, that would be hard.  Spark is unordered, distributed dataframe, so you need a column that defines the order of the rows.  You implied that `Date` doesn't define the order (3-JAN can come before 2-JAN and you need not-the-minimum date, 3-JAN, for the group).  Do you have another column that orders this dataframe?  and could you elaborate "calculation that I need to cascade to Expected result" in the question?

Comment: Update the expected result, where we want to calculate the total mins the ID was in respective status.

Comment: what is your required output? can you populate a new column in the first df?

Comment: why is the 7th row 2880?

Comment: why is the 7th row 2880? - Because the status was still A until it moved to B on 2020-01-03. So we add (1440) no of min in a day to A and continue adding.

Comment: @ThiagarajanDuraisamy but the `date` and `expected` fields are same which would mean zero mins for that record and thus shouldn't it be 1440 instead of 2880?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the following options, to my knowledge:

- windowing/lag, normally should work, didn't you invert here ?

```
F.when(F.col("Status")==F.col("lag_sts"),F.col("lag_date")) .otherwise(F.col("DATE")) )
```

IF Status == lag status then status did not change and therefore column should keep F.col("DATE"), no ?

- (not good but for knowledge purpose since you are starting pySpark) Group by key (ID) and using a flatmap operation. You can easily modify the required value in a python function since, for each given ID you'd have a python list you can order. Beware this is a shuffle-heavy operation and since each ID will be stored in one partition you may face data skewing or out of memory exceptions (if using massive datasets)

Comment: IF Status == lag status then status did not change and therefore column should keep previous date (on when the status was originally set)

Comment: ok understood. You should .show() the dataframe with the lag status and lag date columns added at least we could see if it takes the good values

Comment: I've edited the question with result using show(). Row 5 for status B shows that Lag is computing with existing value and not recursively